# How to map JSON field names to Java object field names

Tags: java, json, rest, field-names

Currently, I'm creating REST Service with Spring.

My request handler in `@RestController`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "employees/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Response setEmployees(@RequestBody Employee employee) {
    Response response = employeeManager.setEmployee(employee);
    return response;
}
```

`Employee` has fields like: `login`,`tabNumber`,`firstName` etc.

The real problem is that my REST service customers want to send request with 
 **another field names, that does not corresponds to Java naming conventions**. Like `TABNUMBER`, `UNITS_NAME` etc. **Jackson API** converts JSON data to Java object corresponding to it field names... How to solve it? How can I bind custom JSON field names to my Java object field names?

---

Comment: You can create one request Entity as per the JSON Request and one Business Entity. Then you can write code to map it accordingly.

Comment: There is similar question here on stackoverflow
[this may be helpful][1]
[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9741134/how-to-map-json-field-names-to-different-object-field-names

Comment: @AbdilFattah thank, it is exactly the answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JsonProperty annotation as below so your clients can send request field name as FIRST_NAME and it can mapped to Employee class :

```
@Data // comes from lombok
class Employee {
    @JsonProperty("FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;

//other fields
}
```